# Sequence which is increasing from a certain point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n) _{n\ge 1}$ be a bounded sequence such that $x_{n+1}\ge x_n$, $\forall n \ge n(\epsilon) $, where $n(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N} $.
So my sequence is increasing from a certain term. Is it still true that $(x_n) _{n\ge 1}$ converges? I believe it is, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A limit of a sequence cannot depend on a finite number of terms. This follows directly from the definition of a limit. Another thing: The notation $n(\epsilon)$ you used doesn't make sense. What is $\epsilon$? Is it some constant that comes up in the definition of the sequence?

Comment: It is just some arbitrary positive integer. In my country it is a common notation, that's why it hasn't occurred to me that it may be a bit odd. :P